# dropdownlists that control checkboxes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a collection of checkboxes that are displayed on a page they represent settings for equipment’s,,
They are displayed using ObjectdataSource and a IENumerable method, that brings distinct settings 
I created a DDL with equipment Names, what I want to do is when a user selects an equipment name the checkboxes for that piece of equipment get checked. Using `AutoPostBack=True` which will reload the page every time a different piece of equipment gets selected. Equipment and their settings are stored in one table.
What is the best way to do this! I can not seem to get my hands on anything similar to this problem. I can Use JavaScript, C#
Any help is appreciated.
`

```
             EnableViewState="true"  >
            <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="Select"  Enabled="true"/> 
        </asp:DropDownList>

         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllequipmentSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Names]">
```

```
<input type="button" value="Select All" class="markerSelectAll"/>
<input type="button" value="Unselect All" class="markerUnSelectAll"/>

<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="SettingsObjectDataSource" SelectMethod="GetDistinctequipmentSettingNames"` 
    TypeName="class"></asp:ObjectDataSource>`
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on wether you are going to use mutiple settings for the same item or if you want to use setting for the item. What you can do, is that you create four tables, one for users, one for equipment, one for settings and one for user specified settings.

Say you have these tables:

```
User: userId, Name
Equipment: equipmentId, Name
Setting: settingID, settingName, equipmentId(so you can have item spesific settings)
```

then for your usersetting table you can do something like this

```
UserSettings: usId, userId, equipmentId, settingId, settingId2, settingId3
```

making settingId2 and up nullable so that you can make items with multiple settings.
then you would just make a sql command to do:

```
insert into UserSettings VALUES (userId, equipmentId, settingId ..... )
```

for loading them into your comboboxes you can do

```
select settingName from Settings where equipmentId = 'equipment your have'
```

then just use a for loop to insert them into the different boxes like this:

```
foreach(DataRow row in YourDataTable.Rows)
 { 
    comboBox.Items.Add(row["settingName"].ToString());


 }
```

Hope this gives you some pointers for which direction to go in

Comment: Thank You For the reply. This makes perfect sense, the issue here is,the tables are already designed, and the whole project was built based on that, what I am trying to work with is one table, In that table there is an  equipment name column and a setting name column,both are PK in that table. it is the only table that stores the data I need. Querying the settings for a certain piece of equipment is straight forward, But the logic behind having a Selected Value in DDL checking the settings for that value. is there a certain flow of operations/Logic behind the design of this task. Thanks